# Android: Insert TableRow into TableLayout in between TableRows dynamacally

Tags: android, android-layout, tablerow, android-tablelayout

In my application four or five row is there which I dynamically inserted into TableLayout.
In the third row one button is there which capture the photo and then it show this photo just below to the button.

In  this application I am also removing some rows from TableLayout depending on above selection by this code

```
tableLayoutRow1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

To showing Image I am creating one more TableRow for Image and I am inserting this row in the TableLayout by following code:

```
tableLayout.addView(tableRowImages, 4, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```

here I am providing index = 4.
this work perfectly first time but next time when I click on button then this row is not showing just below to button.

Comment: Do you use the same index on subsequent insertions, or did you try higher index numbers?

Comment: every time I use same code as mention above to add row for image. Here I am using index number 4 which I mention above.